# Auto-Update a listbox bind with a Database without refreshing the page in Silverlight ...?

Tags: silverlight, linq, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0

I have a list box in silvelight bind with a Observable collection wit is filled form a database , like this :

```
    var item = new AllCommentsPerMaterialCategoryItem { CommenterName = name,
    Text = project.Text, ID = project.ID, NoLike = (int)project.NoLike, SID = l, PID = i,
    VID = (int)project.MID, Date = project.date.ToString() };
    =_viewModel.AllCommentsPerMaterialCategoryItem.Add(item);=  }


    ObservableCollection<AllCommentsPerMaterialCategoryItem> GenreList =   
    _viewModel.AllCommentsPerMaterialCategoryItem; //result from a call to a WCF 
     service which returns the observable collection 
        GenreList1 = _viewModel.AllCommentsPerMaterialCategoryItem;
      mainMenuList.ItemsSource = GenreList;
```

I want whenever someone adds a new item in the database to be automatically filled(updated-refreshed) in list box and also whenever I add a new item to be added to the list

I read that the Observable collection would internally implement "INoifyProbertyChange"
but its not working , also I'm not sure if that would do these requirements or not , i guess it would the second only.

any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` does indeed internally implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. However, it's not going to go to the database for you. You need to either refresh from the database on a timer or set up a duplex service to notify you, and then add/remove items from the `ObservableCollection` as necessary.

The best usage of this would be to create a property returning an instance of the `ObservableCollection` and bind to it, then simply modify the collection as things change. If you're going to swap out the entire collection you'll need to make sure that the property itself notifies of the property changed as there's an important distinction between the `ObservableCollection` notifying the UI that its collection has changed and notifying that the variable that stored it changed to a different collection. The latter there doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example for the timer ?

Comment: greate for the timer thank you , but about the INotifyPropertyChanged,its not refreshing my listbox

Comment: okay , thank you , i ended up clearing the collection and re-adding it at any change